# after chrome updating my flutter app crashes the new bug

Tags: android, google-chrome, flutter, flutter-web

after chrome updating my app crashes

my app uses a some youtube library [here is the link I`m using](https://pub.dev/packages/youtube_player_flutter)

and it shows youtube video in my app

at first time I had no idea why my app is shutting down

and then I kept watching the logging

and then I realized there is something like this

```
I/chromium( 9537): [INFO:CONSOLE(384)] "Unrecognized feature: 'picture-in-picture'.", source: 
https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfltpcih3/www-widgetapi.js (384)
D/SensorManager( 9537): registerListener :: 19, Samsung Game Rotation Vector, 16666, 0,
E/chromium( 9537): [ERROR:validation_errors.cc(76)] Invalid message: 
VALIDATION_ERROR_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED (content.mojom.SynchronousCompositorControlHost.0 )
E/chromium( 9537): [ERROR:render_process_host_impl.cc(4867)] Terminating render process for bad Mojo 
message: Received bad user message: Validation failed for 
content.mojom.SynchronousCompositorControlHost.0  [VALIDATION_ERROR_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED 
(content.mojom.SynchronousCompositorControlHost.0 )
E/chromium( 9537): [ERROR:bad_message.cc(27)] Terminating renderer for bad IPC message, reason 123
D/SensorManager( 9537): unregisterListener :: 19, Samsung Game Rotation Vector,
E/chromium( 9537): [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(125)] Renderer process (10055) crash detected 
(code -1).
E/chromium( 9537): [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(90)] Render process (10055) kill (OOM or update) 
wasn't handed by all associated webviews, killing application.
Lost connection to device.
```

it seems like something has a problem with "chromium" and the "browser"

and then I searched it it was something like "chrome"

and after another device updated chrome and then it crashes too (just before it was working)

so I`m 100% sure of it

the app made by flutter

I really need help I`m in the emergency situation 
the users getting out

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue from https://github.com/sarbagyastha/youtube_player_flutter/issues/188

thanks ClemaX

but it still has a risk as new Chrome version updated I guess